# Canopy version of MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql-python, enthought, canopy

I am running Enthought Canopy, python version 2.7.3, and am having difficulties using the module MySQLdb.  I installed MySQL_Python 1.2.3 from the Canopy Package Manager, but when I run my code I get

```
  File "pyfits_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as mdb
  File "/home/cmessick/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Line 2 of my code simply says

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
```

I also tried

```
from MySQL_python import MySQLdb as mdb
```

and got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyfits_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from MySQL_python import MySQLdb as mdb
ImportError: No module named MySQL_python
```

Does anybody have any suggestions to make Enthought Canopy work with MySQLdb?

Edit: Not sure it matters, but I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Second Edit: I figured out how to add to the module search path, so at the beginning of my code before anything else I now have:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/')
```

Once I do this, it works.  Does anybody have a more permanent solution that I won't have to implement every time?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question now, but I just ran into the same problem with EPD 7.3-2 64-bit (not Canopy) on Ubuntu 13.10.  The following approach fixed the issue for me:

```
cd /path/to/epd/lib
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so libcrypto.so.6
sudo ln -s libssl.so libssl.so.6
```

After this change, you should be able to import MySQLdb.

In your "fix," it appears you are adding the system python dist-packages directory to your EPD python search path; in general, you probably don't want to do this.  Use enpkg to manage your EPD installation, and don't make your EPD python installation dependent upon the configuration of your system python.

Comment: Might want to direct your comment to Roman C. as a comment under his answer.